# How to define hadoop cascading tap to different path according to file name?

Tags: hadoop, cascading

I use Hadoop cascading to process data on HDFS just as below:

```
Tap inTap_file = new Hfs(new TextDelimited(true, "|~|"), data_hadoop_inPath + "order_summary/*.txt");
Tap outTap_file = new Hfs(new TextDelimited(true, "|~|"), data_hadoop_workingPath + "order_summary");

    Pipe copyFilePipe = new Pipe("copy");
    Pipe filePipe = null;
    try {
        filePipe = PipeFactory.getPipe("order_summary_Pipe", order_summary_fields);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to get order summary pipe!", e);
    }

    FlowDef flowDef_fileType = FlowDef.flowDef().addSource(copyFilePipe, inTap_file)
            .addTailSink(filePipe, outTap_file);
    flowDef_fileType.setName("OrderSumDailyFlow");
```

Here is the problem:  there're multiple files under inbox.  I use *.txt to match all the files.  After first file has been processed, "data_hadoop_workingPath + order_summary" destination has been created.  When processing second file, there's error says "data_hadoop_workingPath + order_summary already exist."  I noticed there's SinkMode in cascading but SinkMode.UPDATE doesn't work for Hadoop.  How can I use different sink path for each file?  What's the best practice here?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to not put the output file in the `outTap_file`. It will generate part files.

```
Tap outTap_file = new Hfs(new TextDelimited(true, "|~|"),
   data_hadoop_workingPath + "order_summary");
```

Mention only the path where you want to write. Like mentioned below

```
Tap outTap_file = new Hfs(new TextDelimited(true, "|~|"),
   data_hadoop_workingPath);
```